# Как реализовать пользовательскую агрегатную функцию?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу создать свою пользовательскую агрегатную функцию, но что-то вообще не могу понять как это реализовать в SQL. Читал документацию, но все равно как-то не могу понять действий.

У меня сейчас вот такой запрос, где я суммирую умноженные числа:

```
select sum(Dprice*Price) from F
```

Но я хочу сделать свою агрегатную функцию, чтобы было так:

```
select agg(dpr,pri) from F
```

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_own_aggregate_sfunc (numeric, numeric, numeric)
RETURNS numeric AS
$$
        SELECT $1 + $2*$3;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' STRICT;

CREATE AGGREGATE my_own_aggregate(numeric, numeric)
(
        INITCOND = 0.0,
        STYPE = numeric,
        SFUNC = my_own_aggregate_sfunc
);

select my_own_aggregate(dpr,pri) from F;
```

Собственно и всё. В базовом случае (а у вас как раз такой) у вас есть `sfunc`, которая принимает параметрами `current state value` и переданные агреггирующей функции параметры. Что-то с ними делает, выдаёт результат. Этот результат будет передан как `current state value` на следующем вызове с данными следующей строки - либо возвращён как результат всей агрегации.

Comment: Большое спасибо ! 
Я то думал, что все, что вы указали в обычно функции нужно указывать в создаваемой агрегатной =( 
Теперь в случаешь нужды буду использовать)